# Getting content from an inframe using domCrawler component of Symfony or cURL

Tags: dom, web-crawler

How can I get content from an iframe using domCrawler component?

I'm trying to access the div inside the iframe but no results are returning.

Here is my code:

```
$crawler->filter('div#features')
```

This div features is inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that this will not work with symfony. I was able to get the content changing the user agent to mobile because when mobile version there's no iframe.